# Profile pictures not loading with HTTPS

Tags: alternate-access-mapping

**What I have?**

A SharePoint 2010 web site exposed to internet with the following alternate access mapping:

Internal URL Zone Public URL for Zone

_http://servername             Default   _http://servername

_https://domainname.com   Internet _https://domainname.com

_http://domainname.com     Internet _https://domainname.com

**What Problem am I facing?**

I have Note Board web part which displays the user image. This image is referring to HTTP url. So, the image is not displaying.

Can someone tell me what am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing nothing, profile images for some reason (bug) do not obey AAMs.

You could try to fix with HttpModule or jQuery, but i'm just waiting for SP1

Comment: But, on the My Profile page the image displays properly. Is the bug in search? I did a full crawl also.

Comment: yeah, some places it displays right, and other places it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

while it might not be considered best practice, you could try URL redirection in IIS. http://forums.iis.net/t/1153050.aspx should work as a starting point.